# Find all the angles between $-2\pi$ and $-\pi$ which satisfy the equation $\sec \frac{7}{5}x = -2$.

Tags: trigonometry

> Find all the angles between $-2\pi$ and $-\pi$ which satisfy the equation $\sec \frac{7}{5}x = -2$.

Can anybody help me with this question? I have never attempted a question where the angle range is in the negatives. I'm aware of the ASTC quadrants.

Comment: Better to write out the question in the body here, than to ask people to chase it on another site. Oh, and what's a "qns"?

Comment: Have you figured out the quadrants which lie between $-2\pi$ and $-\pi$?  In which of those quadrants is the secant negative?

Comment: Have you tried plotting the function? `Plot[{Sec[7x/5], -2}, {x,-2Pi,-Pi}]` will give you an idea of where the solutions are (code is Mathematica but any software will do).

Answer (score 0):

Given:
$$\sec\Bigl(\frac{7x}{5}\Bigr)= -2$$
$$\cos\Bigl(\frac{7x}{5}\Bigr)= \frac{-1}{2}$$
in the range $[-2\pi,-\pi]$

So, $$\frac{7x}{5}=\cos^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{-1}{2}\Bigr)$$
in the interval $[-2\pi,-\pi]$
$$\cos(-\pi+\frac{-\pi}{3})=\cos\Bigl(\frac{-4\pi}{3}\Bigr)=\cos\Bigl(\frac{4\pi}{3}\Bigr)=\frac{-1}{2}$$
$$\cos^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{-1}{2}\Bigr)=\frac{-4\pi}{3}=\frac{7x}{5}$$
Therefore, $$x=\frac{-20\pi}{21}=-2.99$$

Here, x doesn't have two solutions and you will find that to be obvious by having a look at the graph.

Comment: The range of the arccosine function is $[0, \pi]$.